# Variable subtitution in FOL formula with nested and outer quantifiers

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am given the formula: $\Psi={{\forall}}x\exists y\left(\exists z{{\forall}}xR\left(x,z,w\right)\land\exists wP\left(w,x,z\right)\right)$
for which I'm required to determine if a given simultaneous subtitution $\Psi\left\{ \frac{t_{1}}{x},\frac{t_{2}}{y},\frac{t_{3}}{z},\frac{t_{4}}{w}\right\} $ is valid.

In the reference I have, which does not include explainations, the variables $x,w$ are renamed in the following manner: $\Psi={{\forall}}x\exists y\left(\exists z{{\forall}}\mathbf{u}R\left(\mathbf{u},z,w\right)\land\exists \mathbf{v}P\left(\mathbf{v},x,z\right)\right)$ and then, the general subtitution results in: $\Psi\left\{ \frac{t_{1}}{x},\frac{t_{2}}{y},\frac{t_{3}}{z},\frac{t_{4}}{w}\right\}={{\forall}}x\exists y\left(\exists z{{\forall}}uR\left(u,t_3,t_4\right)\land\exists vP\left(v,t_1,t_3\right)\right)$.

I'm trying to explain myself why it was done this way:

1. $x$ is renamed to $u$ in the first term of the conjunction simply because it is already bounded in the outer scope - so the nested bounding in this term is useless, and in order to make it effective, a "new" variable $u$ must be introduced.
2. $w$ is renamed to $v$ in the second term of the conjunction because it is free in the first term, so a future subtitution of $w$ could be harmful, otherwise.
3. The subtitution - the only thing I don't understand is why $t_1$ subtitutes $x$ in the second term of the conjunction. $x$ is bounded in the outer scope, and thus affects this term, so it seems to me it shouldn't be subtituted. But I guess my understanding lacks something.

Are my explainations make sense?
Can someone please explain me the 3rd point?
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You cannot subst the rightmost $x$ with $t_1$ because it is bound by the leading quantifier $\forall x$. The same with the subst of the leftmost $z$ with $t_3$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So the reference was wrong w.r.t to the rightmost $x$, as I thought. I also assume it holds for any $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4$, right? The question of a subtitutable $t_i$ is a different one, once they are placed.

Comment: I think so... In **my** understanding, the rule for subst is : $(∀y α)^x_
t = ∀y α$, if $x = y$ and $∀y (α)^x_t$, if $x \ne y$.

Comment: This is my understanding as well. Thank you!